# Preserving CSS styles with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styling

I have a web service where people can edit their pages CSS, but I have a bar on the footer of that page that I want to make consistend on every page...

People are, right now, able to "remove" it with CSS and I really didn't want to go and parse the CSS to remove rules related to that bar... Is there a way to preserve the styles or re-aply them after load to keep the bar always visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the user-created CSS as you save it; adding descendant selectors to all their rules, you can limit the effect of their styles to an element of your choosing. If you take this HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="userEditableArea">
      <h2>Stylable</h2>
      <p>Users can style this section.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footerBar">
      Users can't style this section.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The user creates the following stylesheet, trying to hide your footer:

```
h2 {font-size:2em;}
p {font-color:#333;}
#footerBar {display:none;}
```

When the user saves their styles, you parse through and add `#userEditableArea` to all of their rules, so they only work on elements inside `<div id="userEditableArea">`. This should be pretty easy to accomplish with a regex pass or two.

```
#userEditableArea h2 {font-size:2em;}
#userEditableArea p {font-color:#333;}
#userEditableArea #footerBar {display:none;}
```

Anything you don't want them to mess with, put outside of #userEditableArea.

This should be pretty robust - more so than using !important rules or high-specificity selectors, and doesn't require any JS.

Comment: This is actually a very interesting solution! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 2):

The jquery [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method lets you set css properties. If you set any properties you want to enforce on the window load, they should override what was set in the css files.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $("#footer").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

You might also look at using an [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) rule, to trump the styles in the user editable style sheet.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it :) But they could use more than just visibility, they could use a negative `text-indent`, `display:none` or make the text color transparent or the same as the background.

Comment: These techniques require you to set every property you want to protect (which you probably don't want to do), and rely on specificity and !important, neither of which are reliable.

Also, they rely on javascript, which you really don't need for a robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the bar in an iframe.

Answer (score -1):

You could try two methods:

1. Use the `!important` flag in your CSS
2. Add the bar using script, which means you are adding it and its style after the page has loaded. But don't use an ID or class name, so they can't target it easily with CSS.

Comment: they can always figure out the structure of the page later on, and wouldn't necessarily need to target the bar directly using an id or class.

Comment: A smart enough person will ALWAYS be able to disable or hide any part of a page no matter what you do. Have you heard of Greasemonkey or Stylish addons for Firefox?

Comment: Also, I asked this question a while back about allowing users to add their own stylesheet... there are some security issues with which you should be aware: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534012/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-let-users-add-their-own-stylesheet

Comment: fudgey, it's not about smart people doing whatever they want on their own machine, but site pages that are globally accessible to all. you could hide/remove facebook wrappers, and have all apps run in full screen on your own machine, but if a script/css does it so the app is running full screen for all users, then facebook has a huge problem.

Comment: Neither of these techniques are very reliable.

If you rely on !important, you need to define every style property you want to protect - !important may (partially) protect the styles you've set, but it can't protect the styles that aren't set.

Elements added using scripts can be targeted with CSS whether you give them ID's and classes, or not. Besides, you want to be able to style the thing yourself, right?